# I want to know why this result is not 1000000

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I used the thread pool to create 100 threads, added money, and used synchronized, but the result did not reach 1000000.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ThreadPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            Thread t=new MyThread();
            pool.execute(t);
        }
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread{

    private static int money=0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        addMoney();
    }

    public synchronized void addMoney() {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            money+=1;
        System.out.println(money);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are synced threads well enough, please have a lock & unlock in java

Comment: Nope. synchronized method is synchronized on each thread, so basically unsynchronized. Try a synchronized block on the same object.

Comment: @DrPhil - It we want to be pedantic .... :-)  The methods are synchronizing on `this`.  In this case, `this` will be an instance of `MyThread`.  But that instance won't be the current thread ... because the `MyThread::start` is not going to be called anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `synchronized` keyword that you added to your `addMoney` method uses `this` as the intrinsic lock. Since `this` is pointing to each of the thread instances, and each thread calls this method only once, it doesn't have an effect.

To synchronize access across the threads, you could specify a global lock instance explicitly, e.g. the `ThreadPool` class:

```
public void addMoney() {
    synchronized(ThreadPool.class) {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            money+=1;
        System.out.println(money);
    }
}
```

You could achieve almost the same in your case by declaring the `addMoney` method as `static`. In that case the intrinsic lock will be the `MyThread` class instead:

```
public static synchronized void addMoney() {
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        money+=1;
    System.out.println(money);
}
```

You can find more details in the Java documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: I'm pretty impressed that the language designers made `static synchronized foo()` work like it should work.

Comment: It's best not to synchronize on a class. Any thread using that class blocks until it acquires the monitor. You better define a `lock` field, initialize it (e.g. `new Object()`) and synchronize on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each of your tasks is synchronizing on a different object while accessing and updating the shared static variable.  That means that there is no mutual exclusion between the worker threads.  That means that the value computed by your application is liable to be unpredictable and/or platform specific.  (Unless you get lucky ...)

One approach to fixing that would be to change `addMoney` to be a `static synchronized` method.  That would cause the threads to synchronize on the `MyThread.class` object.  However, if you do that, you will find that your application is *effectively* single threaded ... because only one of your `MyThread` instances will be able to execute its `addMoney` method at one time.

It is not clear what the correct fix is because it is not clear what this "toy" example is trying to demonstrate.  But the alternative approach I mentioned should at least reliably compute the result.

---

You should not be extending `Thread`.  Your `MyThread` class should be replaced with a class that implements `Runnable`.  What you are doing here is to use a `Thread` object as if it was just a `Runnable`.  That is a bad idea.  The `ExecutorService` that you are using will take care of thread creation.  You need to feed it "tasks" not "threads".

Comment: I understand.Thank you for your answer

Comment: Thread is not conducive to resource sharing, Runable is better. But the result will be 1000,000, because only one is added at a time

Comment: @limstorm - *"Thread is not conducive to resource sharing, Runable is better."*  No that's not the problem with `Thread` versus `Runnable`.  Neither are "conducive to resource sharing" if you perform 10,000 operations on the shared variable while holding the lock.  (Hint: consider using a synchronized block, or putting the loop in the `run()` method.)  The issue with `MyThread` is that you instantiate a substantial `Thread` object and then don't make use of the infrastructure it provides.  It is poor style ... and a bit wasteful.

Comment: To be fair, it’s a historical design mistake of the Java inventors, to let `Thread` implement `Runnable`, misleading to this kind of use. Note that when you create a class implementing `Runnable`, you may create one instance of it and call `pool.execute` with that one object 100 times, to create up to hundred threads in the pool executing it. Then, the `synchronized` instance method will work correctly, as it will synchronize on the same object. Removing the `static` modifier from the field would it make even cleaner then.